# How can I disable inline javascript but allow external .js file?

Tags: xss

(please excuse my poor English, I'll try to make myself clear as much as possible, thanks!)

I'm not an advanced user. I want to block any internal javascript (Internal Style Sheet) code, but allow all external .js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable inline javascript using the UserCSP addon in Firefox. If you set up a CSP for a site it will by default block inline JS and functions that create js from strings like eval.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/newusercspdesign/

Comment: That plugin seems to be broken. Any other ideas?